# how to improve accuracy of Lat long using Core location manager

Tags: iphone, ios4, location, core-location

What can be the possible steps to improve the accuracy of the Latitude and Longitude of the iPhon.

As there are many ways and normally we use

```
self.TlocationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];

self.TlocationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest; 


self.TlocationManager.distanceFilter = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;

self.TlocationManager.delegate = self;  

[self.TlocationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Aprat from this what extra we need to implement for getting best Location from  the iPhone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can't change *that* code to make it any better... but you *can* make some interesting checks in your delegate:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

Where newLocation contains the following properties:

```
  horizontalAccuracy
  verticalAccuracy
```

You should monitor the accuracy until it reaches the point you're happy with before you start "using" the values for lat/long.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CLLocation

Answer (score 2):

NO, that is the best you can do in code.